# Unable to embed the image file in the template uploaded by user

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

I am trying to load the uploaded image in the template. The image is getting correctly uploaded and the url is also correct but I am still getting the 404 error. The error is:- GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/complaints_image/motivational-inspirational-quotes-30.jpg 404 (Not Found)

The image is present in the folder :-
[inside the media folder image is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ7LQ.png)

**template**

```
{% if complaint.media %}
 <img src="{{ complaint.media.url }}" height="100px" width="100px" >
{% endif %}
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_DIR  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**models.py**

```
class Complaints(models.Model):
  media = models.ImageField(upload_to='complaints_image',blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ComplaintForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta():
    model = Complaint
    fields = ('department','heading','text','media',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You are getting this error because media files are not served automatically (by default).

---

If your `MEDIA_URL` is defined as `'/media/'`, then you can serve your media files by adding the following snippet to your `entry-level urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Read [Serving files uploaded by a user during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) for more details.

---

#### Note: This way of serving media (and static) files is not suitable for production use!

Read [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/deployment/) for more details on what to do for the production server.

Comment: Thanks, It fixed it